# Deadlock while syncronizing Spring entity manager query

Tags: spring, multithreading, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I'm developing an application using Spring which directs the DB using entity manager with `@PersistenceContext` injection. the application is executed in multiple threads, each in its own `@Transactional` scope.

As part of the thread process it should go and call :

```
entityManager.createQuery("some statement").getResultList()
```

This should return if an object exists on the DB and if not it will persist it. because i am using multiple threads i have put the call in a syncronized block on a shared object like this:

```
synchronized (getLock())
{
    List<SomeObject> listOfObjects = entityManager.createQuery("some statement").getResultList();

    if(listOfObjects == null || listOfObjects.size() < 1)
    {
       createObject();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I'm running this the process get stuck on the call to the `getResultList` and never released. Moreover, when i run the code and creating only one thread I get the same behavior.

if i change the flushMode to COMMIT the process is released but the results are not reflected well because the different threads could end at different times and the one creating the object will not necessarily be the one to end first.

my persistence xml is:

```
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="syncAdapterUnit"
                      transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="10"/>
            <property name="format_sql" value="false"/>

            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The spring bean xml:

```
    <beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="managerFactoryBean" class="com.amdocs.dim.ManagerFactory" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy"> 
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="syncAdapterUnit"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
        <property name="database" value="ORACLE"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cifDBProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        <property name="location" value="classpath:APP-INF/conf/database.properties"/>
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_FALLBACK"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" scope="singleton">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I believe that the flush process is the one which blocks the app but didn't manage to understand why.

Comment: You are using hibernate and spring then use them, don't work around them. Use database locking and let hibernate do locking for you. Easier coding and transparent. Just specify the lock mode for the query.

Comment: thanks for the comment @M.Deinum. the problem is that i need to do the following steps:
1.check the shared object existence.
2.create the object the first time i see it does not exists.
3.use it in all threads.
This obligates me to make all other threads wait until the object is created by the first one after getting the empty list.

Comment: Add the use case to your question not as comments. Simply put use the database don't try to be smarter, as as soon as you have multiple instances of your application your solution will simply break. Also add the spring configuration and a bit more code as there is a bit too little at the moment.

Comment: No it doesn't. You will not be able to solve this with synchronizing the client. Use database locking instead. And as stated either have hibernate specify the lock mode when creating the query or select a broader isolation level on your `@Transactional`. Don't try to do it yourself. Also doing a query, return a list and check it is overkill, just do a count which will be faster.

Comment: ok so one thing i'm missing here in case i want to use the pessimistic lock. lets say that a thread entered the critical section and is creating the shared object and then thread 2 is coming to critical section just before the shared object is created and persisted, i will not be able to lock the object and thread 2 will try to create it as well. in any case 1 of the 2 will manage to create one and the second one will fail but won't be able to know when the fault will happen, in the persist stage, flush time or the commit..do you have some kind of an example of how to do the locking correctly?

Comment: I suggest reading up on transactions and isolation levels and how those align with `@Transactional` and how to use it to your advantage.

Comment: as far as i understood all those functionalities will provide me the ability to manage the case of duplicate insertions of the same object. but in my case the situation is that in case of duplication i don't want to rollback the transaction, i want to know at the moment of writing that the object was created already and use it for the other threads. in this case of: a.fetch object(return empty). b.some long op. c.try to write object (already there so use existing and continue transaction) the isolation and locking mechanism will fail to provide an answer. i'm out of ideas here...

Comment: No it won't... You are overthinking this. When the method is called and a proper isolation level is given, the query will block further access. Only a single connection/thread has access. That can query and either return or query, the others will block until the tx releases the lock. It might be that other threads get a tx timeout depending on the timeout settings. But again it will work and you are trying to solve things that have already been solved 30+ years ago.

Comment: ok so read some about the isolation & persistence context behavior and as far as i understand now if i set the correct level of isolation i have only one point which i'm not sure how to handle: a case when 2 threads read shared objects and gets empty value, then 1 thread creates it and when the second tries to do the  same it will get the correct exception says it is already there. in that point i should recover and use the existing but the exception does not always occurs on persist (can happen in flush time/ comit) and i need to continue the transaction.... any suggestions?